# Implement web worker in browser extension - Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, web-worker, browser-extension

I'm trying to implement a web worker in my vue web extension. To start implementing the code I've writed these couples of lines but I get this error from the extension: `Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined`, or this other error `Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined`, the second error is caused by the worker.js file. I need to use a script that isn't available using `import` that is declared in the `externals` field of the vue config file and normally works fine in the extension and this is why I'm using `importScripts()`.

Since I need a workflow where the user after a button click starts the web worker, I've used the messaging system to tell the background scripts to start the web worker, here is the code

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_extName__",
  "description": "__MSG_extDescription__",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "https://*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16.png",
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "128": "icons/128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/worker.js",
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "page_action": {}
}
```

**background.js**

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (message) => {
  if( message.status === 'startDownload' ){
    const worker = new Worker(browser.runtime.getURL('js/worker.js'))
    console.log(worker)
    worker.postMessage(['hello'])
  }
})
```

**worker.js**

```
importScripts(browser.runtime.getURL('./assets/m3u8.js'))

onmessage = (msg) => {
  console.log('message from background script!', msg)
}
```

popup.js file

```
mounted() {
 browser.runtime.sendMessage({status: 'startDownload'})
}
```

Is something wrong in the code, how I can make the things work?

Comment: Remove `"js/worker.js",` from manifest.json. Also remove browser.runtime.getURL, it's not needed.

Comment: I need to remove `browser.runtime.getURL()` from the `importScripts()` right?

Comment: Yes, usually it's only needed if you expose something to a web page.